# Return statement with loops and exceptions

Tags: c++

I have an API which throws and I have to retry a certain number of times before I fail. My code is as follows:

```
bool bar(int i) 
{
    // edit: missed the 'if' 
    if(i == 4) return true; 
    throw std::runtime_error("error");
}

bool foo() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        try
        {
            return bar(i); // cannot change implementation
        }
        catch(...)
        {
            if(i <4) continue;
            throw;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << foo();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Why am I getting this warning? It looks safe.

Comment: You are missing an `if` before `(i == 4)`.

Comment: Don't use exceptions for general flow control, that's not what they are for. The entire basis for your example is wrong. If this is an actual reflection of your code you should fix it.

Comment: Actually, that is how my code looks like. How should I refactor it to make it look better?
I have no control over the API which throws.

Comment: Put a `return false` or whatever at the end of the function so the compiler sees it always returns something even though the throw should make that unreachable code.  You have the same problem in `foo`.

Comment: It may be to much for the static analyzer to swallow. You've got a loop, a catch and a conditional continue. Just put a return at the end as a failsafe.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like whatever compiler you're using can't figure out that the value of i in your for() loop is never going to make it up to 5. In the general case, that's a lot to ask of a compiler, even if it's obvious to a human observer in this case.